# Customs for waving arba minim three times in each direction

Tags: minhag, number, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I get why we shake the arba minim in all directions, but why do some have the custom of shaking them three times in each direction?

Comment: Hello Michael -- I edited the title of your question for clarity, because I thought it was a little too general. (I also added a tag) .....If you don't like it, you can fix it [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47296/edit)

Answer (score 6):

The Yerushalmi Sukka 15b halacha 8 seems to be the source for shaking three times :

דף טו,ב פרק ג הלכה ח גמרא  הא בהודו לא.  להוציא אף באנא ה' הצליחה נא.  רב חייה בר אשי בשם רב זה שהוא משכים לצאת לדרך נוטל לולב ומנענע.  שופר ותוקע.  לכשתגיע עונות קריאת שמע ה"ז קורא את שמע ומתפלל.  **תני צריך לנענע ג' פעמים** **ר' זעירה בעי הכין חד והכין חד.  או הכין והכין חד.  תמן תנינן צריך לכסכס ג' פעמים בין כל דבר ודבר ר' זעירה בעי הכין חד והכין חד או הכין והכין חד:** It is a machlokes how the three is done see the [Shulchan Aruch 651:9 with the Nosei Keilim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3034)

The Ramabm Hilchos Lulav 7:9,10 holds that one has to shake it three times.

Halacha 9

"משיגביה ארבעה מינין אלו בין שהגביהן כאחת בין בזה אחר זה בין בימין בין בשמאל יצא. והוא שיגביהן דרך גדילתן אבל שלא דרך גדילתן לא יצא. ומצוה כהלכתה שיגביה אגודה של שלשה מינין בימין ואתרוג בשמאל ויוליך ויביא ויעלה ויוריד **וינענע הלולב שלש פעמים** בכל רוח ורוח:

Halacha 10

כיצד מוליך ומנענע ראש הלולב שלש פעמים ומביא ומנענע ראש הלולב שלש פעמים וכן בעליה וירידה. והיכן מוליך ומביא בשעת קריאת ההלל בהודו לה' כי טוב תחלה וסוף ובאנא ה' הושיעה נא וכל היום כשר לנטילת לולב ואינו נוטל בלילה:"

The Shulchan Aruch 651:9 brings this as the halacha. However, the Rama has a variation of doing the shaking three times with making a rustle sound.

The way the M.B. explains the Ramma's opinion is to shake while moving it back and forth three times as opposed to the Mechaber who says to shake it three times during to to and fro motion which is only done once in each direction.

Comment: the reason i did not expound on the different opinions is because that was not the question asked I just noted the difference the main source is the yerushalmi which states two ways of doing it , you are  ore than welcome to edit it

Comment: I threw it in there and deleted my other comment

Comment: Thank you. However, i'm not sure that these sources explain why we shake three times - rather they just seem to indicate that we shake three times.

Comment: @MichaelLewis Looks like a good answer to me: You asked why we do so, and the answer is that the Talmud et al. say so.

Answer (score 1):

HaRav Hayim Wital, in his *Peri Etz Hayim* (Sha'ar HaLulav, Pereq Gimel) in the name of his teacher *HaAR"I Z"L*, [explains](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/vital/pri_ec_chajim.htm) (my translation):

> לכן אנו מנענעים בכל יום, לכל רוחות, להמשיך אור מכל הבחי' שבו. ובהלל אנו מנענעין בארבע מקומות - בהודו לי"י פעם אחד, שלושה נענועים לכל רוח, לכל ששה רוחות, הרי ח"י נענועים. [...] ובאנא י"י הושיעה, ב' פעמים, שכופלין אותו. ובהודו לי"י בסוף, פעם אחד, הרי ע"ב נענועין בכל יום בהלל, מלבד פעם ראשונה כשאנו מברכין על הלולב
>
> Therefore, we shake [the minim] everyday, in all [six] directions, to extend light from all facets of [each direction]. And during *Hallel*, we shake [the minim] at four points - one time during "Hodu LaShem", **three shakes in each of the six directions**, which totals 18 shakes. And during "Ana HaShem Hoshi'ah", two times, for we recite it twice. And another time during "Hodu LaShem" at the end, which totals 72 shakes everyday during *Hallel* (apart from the first time when we recite the blessing on the Lulav).

As HaRav Wital explains in this chapter of *Peri Etz Hayim*, the 72 shakes (3 * 6 * 4 = 72) bring us to the [gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) of the word *Hesed* (חסד), which is the Divine Attribute we are trying to draw down upon us from Above.